# Calculus- Chain rule problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I'm solving my calculus homework and got stuck on one of them. It's about using chain rule at 2 variable function. Help me, please. [image: Problem] [image: my answer]

Comment: We can use differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: Adding to Rohans comment, use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement). Note that $F'(x) = (E_{x} + E_{y}) \rvert_{y = x}$.

Comment: Actually, I solved this problem until that part before posting, Mattos. But after doing that, there is an integration I can't simplify. ( I think it cannot be represented by elementary function.) So is the answer like what I add on my post?

Comment: @Kim Your $F'$ is correct. I wrote that $F' = (E_{x} + E_{y})\rvert_{y=x}$ as it gave you two different ways to compute $F'$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much!